# Is there ever a time when an exception can occur due to a user-invoked action and does not require letting the user know?

Tags: exception

In implementing exception handling, it seems to follow the same pattern that any code which is invokable by the user (i.e. behind a button), needs try/catch/finally, and then has to propagate to the user (throw) and then show a message box to the user.

Is there ever any time when an exception can occur due to an action invoked by the user, but does not require letting the user know?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  One common example: a window is opened which is supposed to monitor the progress of some long-running task (whose execution is independent of the window) and the window is subsequently closed and Disposed.  Just as the window is being disposed, the thread whose progress is being monitored attempts to use a BeginInvoke to update its progress indicator.  The BeginInvoke will end up throwing an InvalidOperationException as a direct consequence of the user having decided to close the window at the precise moment he did, but there's no need to bother the user about it.  Simply swallow the exception and move on.